# MongoDB Collection as Dictionary

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking at having a mongodb collection.

As I understand it, a collection is just a group of objects.

I'm curious if it's possible to store a collection as a single object with multiple keys (as a dictionary).

Or if I can store multiple objects with a key value pair and somehow parse it into a Dictionary in c#.

Comment: But why? If you want to store a dictionary, why not create a collection with a single document which contains a dictionary?

Comment: @John it just makes the code more complicated, then I have to treat it as though there's a list with a single dictionary inside of it. What's the point of doing that if there might be a way to just have the dictionary?

Comment: If that's the way you feel, perhaps you're more in need of a key value datastore instead?

Comment: @John that's a valid point. The problem I have there is that another collection I use for this project utilizes a document model that would be difficult to replicate in something like MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out what I need.

I can store each object as a key value pair and then
parse it within the c# like this:

```
    private readonly IMongoCollection<KeyValuePair<string, Object>> _logs;

    public Dictionary<string, Object> Get() => _logs.Find(pair => true).ToList().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=> x.Value);
```

Comment: Don't forget to slap a unique index on "Key" so you don't get duplicates. :)